# div stacking/layout with css or javascript

Tags: jquery, css

so i have 4 divs (i actually have many more but this will simplify the question). i want to display them in two columns. the 4 divs vary in height. the number of actual divs in the end will vary. 
so if i have this

```
<div id="1" style="height: 200px" class="inline">some content here</div>
<div id="2" style="height: 600px" class="inline">some content here</div>
<div id="3" style="height: 300px" class="inline">some content here</div>
<div id="4" style="height: 200px" class="inline">some content here</div>
```

with styling thus

```
.inline { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 48%;}
```

so #1 would go left and then #2 would shove up beside it to the right, great, but the #3 will not slide up the 400px to fit nicely below #1. (of course)... it goes on the left side but at 600px from the top clearing the bottom of #2. etc...

how would i get the divs to slide up into the empty spaces, is it possible with css? jquery maybe?
i know i could write column divs to mark it up, but since the number of divs constantly change and the heights vary according to content. It would be nice to just get rid of the space since we dont really care about the order.

any thoughts?

Comment: try floating the divs to left and right alternatively

Comment: Off-topic, but DOM element id's can't begin with numbers.

Comment: i know, it was for the sake of clarity... sorry

Comment: @mahesh... wanted something a little more "automatic"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is impossible with pure CSS, you are going to need separate divs for each column. Fortunately, you can achieve this using jQuery. Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    var odd_divs = $('div.inline:odd');
    var even_divs = $('div.inline:even');
    var left = $('<div id="left-column" class="column"/>').append(odd_divs);
    var right = $('<div id="right-column" class="column" />').append(even_divs);
    $('#somewhere').append(left).append(right);
});
```

And change your CSS to this:

```
.column {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**EDIT**

As Brian McKenna noted, it is actually possible to achieve this effect using CSS floats. You can use jQuery to add the classnames as so:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.inline:odd').addClass('box-left');
    $('div.inline:even').addClass('box-right');
});
```

Comment: i was interested in if there was a way to achieve it besides float...
thanks for the above, an interesting solution... combine floats with adding the style automatically...

Comment: @liz - I don't understand. This answer involves floats and it's also not going to work for people that have JavaScript disabled. I can see the benefit of it being automatic but most of the time accessibility should be the most important metric.

Comment: okay i played with this some and actually the first of your solutions without the float is more reliable in display than using floats.

Comment: if javascript is disabled then they will still get the data just in a single column. no biggie, still the data is accessible. there will be a separate style sheet if they print. i can also make the first class be for the no javascript solution and then change the class with javascript. i did not use the floating option, it was still producing buggy effects for what i wanted. .. make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem correctly. I'm guessing you want it to look like this example I just made, http://jsbin.com/emeja

The HTML I used was like so:

```
<div style="height: 200px" class="box-left">some content here</div>
<div style="height: 600px" class="box-right">some content here</div>
<div style="height: 300px" class="box-left">some content here</div>
<div style="height: 200px" class="box-right">some content here</div>
```

The CSS is like so:

```
.box-left { float: left; clear: left; width: 48%;}
.box-right { float: right; clear: right; width: 48%;}
```

The trick is [floating](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/) the boxes, clearing them so that boxes won't show up next to boxes in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

You prettymuch have to split the colunms up and assign every second div to a different container.

```
<div id="content" style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div id="left" style="width: 48%; float: left;">
    <!-- This is where every odd numbered div goes -->
  </div>
  <div id="left" style="width: auto; margin-left: 50%;">
    <!-- This is where every even numbered div goes -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're having trouble selecting your content in your for-loop for creating these arbitrary divs this will help:

```
// Render Header
for(int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
{
   if (i % 2 == !)
     continue;

   // Render my div inside left colunm
}

// Render In-Between

for(int i = 0; i < list.count(); i++)
{
   if (i % 2 == !)
     continue;

   // Render my div inside left colunm
}

// Render Footer
```

This code relys on the modulo to select your items from your list and should put them in the right place, then your internal divs should sit right underneath each other inside a colunm.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in IE (the Divs will snuggle-up nicely) but doesn't work in in FF etc (see [this page](http://www.hilldickinson.com/client_services.aspx) for an example - the links to the right use this theory - I should know, I tried to fix it!)

However, here's a thought from the left-field - may seem like overcomplicating the issue a little but...

[JQuery treeMap](http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article40)?

Goto http://newsmap.js and scratch your brain trying to work out how they did it too? It sounds mad, but that, and treeMap are more complex version of what you are trying to achieve.

Rob